# Powershell Out-file with variable

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I'm trying to write a script that will check if a string is null and if it is output the user name to a file so I can go back and check that file and see who is null.  Below is my code, the script is not writing to the out-file any ideas?

```
$user = "user@domain.com"
#just gets the users info
$user_info = gam info user $user 
$suspended = $user_info | Select-String -pattern "Account Suspended: true"
if ($suspended = $null) {
  $user | Out-File -FilePath C:\scripts\not_suspended.txt -append -Encoding utf8
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning `$null` to `$suspended` in your if statement. Use `-eq` instead to do the comparison:

```
if ($suspended -eq $null) {
  $user | Out-File -FilePath C:\scripts\not_suspended.txt -append -Encoding utf8
}
```